# Google Cloud SDK cURL cloud not resolve host

Tags: json, curl, http-status-code-401, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to setup Google Cloud Api on windows. I spend many hours to fix this issue read all related questions nothing helps!
First I set the variable

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\Desktop\directory\filename.json"

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
   --data "{
    'input':{
    'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
     based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
     touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
    },
    'voice':{
     'languageCode':'en-gb',
     'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
     'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
     'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt
```

As describe in google documentation. But in command line

```
curl: (6) cloud not resolve host: auth
curl: (6) cloud not resolve host: application-default
curl: (6) cloud not resolve host: print-access-token
```

Show me this error. In synthesize-text.txt says that error code 401.

How can I fix this. Any help appreciate.

Edit:
When I excuse the

```
gcloud auth application-default print-acces-token command
```

Returns Environment variable does not exist! But ı excute the set command. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to windows doesn't accept the `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)` usage.

You can try writing the command output for the print-access-token to a file. For instance:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token > token.txt
```

Then you can assign this to an environment variable:

```
set /p token=<token.txt
```

And try running your Text-to-Speech API request like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "%token% \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
   --data "{
    'input':{
    'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
     based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
     touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
    },
    'voice':{
     'languageCode':'en-gb',
     'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
     'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
     'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt
```

Alternatively, you can try using the API Keys for your requests. For instance:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \ 
--data "{ 
'input':{ 
'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, 
based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for 
touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.' 
}, 
'voice':{ 
'languageCode':'en-gb', 
'name':'en-GB-Standard-A', 
'ssmlGender':'FEMALE' 
}, 
'audioConfig':{ 
'audioEncoding':'MP3' 
} 
}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize?key=YOUR_API_KEY" > synthesize-text.txt
```

Comment: I cannot access json file return environment variable does not exist

Comment: You need to set it everytime you open a new CMD window or you can create a [custom environment variable](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-custom-environment-variables-in-windows/)

Comment: I set the json file everytime I open the mcd window but when I try to access the cloud it returns environment variable does not exits. I set the variable as I show in the question. Custom  environment does not work also...

Comment: Have you already executed the `gcloud init` command too? This is to authorize access using your user account credentials. If you have time, you can join in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181948/gcloud-windows) to discuss your scenario